# AWS CloudFormation - How to add Lambda Trigger to existing Cognito User Pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-triggers

I've a preexisting Cognito User Pool. I need create a post confirmation lambda trigger through CloudFormation.

Previously I created other trigger lambda type using `AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping` for example:

```
Resources:
  lambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      MemorySize: 512
      Timeout: 900
      FunctionName: !Ref lambdaFunctionName
      Description: !Ref lambdaDescription
      Handler: !Ref lambdaHandler
      Role: !GetAtt lambdaIAMRole.Arn
      Runtime: python3.10

  LambdaFunctionEventSourceMapping:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping
    Properties:
      EventSourceArn: !GetAtt createArticleQueue.Arn
      FunctionName: !GetAtt lambdaFunction.Arn
      BatchSize: 1
      Enabled: true
      ScalingConfig:
        MaximumConcurrency: !Ref createArticleQueueMaxConcurrency
```

Is there anyway to create an EventSourceMapping to create a cognito user pool post confirmation lambda trigger through CloudFormation?